# Resize UIView to fit its content

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview

The problem is, that I do have a view containing 3 parts.

The first part is a simple **header - same height always!** 
The second part is a simple **description line - same height always!**

Now the problem is the third part. It's a **viewContainer** for dynamically calculated subviews (each of them having a custom controller). The height of the content is dynamic caused by some text information downloaded from a backend. So some times I would need to scroll to be able to read the whole text, sometimes not.

Currently I am doing it this way:

- Calculate the size of the UILabel for a specific text.
- Then resize the parent view so fit the UILabel (if smaller).
- Then resize the scrollView of my **3-Part-ViewController-View** to fit its subviews.

The detail viewController with the dynamic content:

```
    self.labelDescription.text = self.customData.descriptionText;
    [self.labelDescription sizeToFit];
    if(self.view.frame.size.height < (self.labelDescription.frame.size.height + self.labelDescription.frame.origin.y)) {
    CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(0,
                                0,
                                self.view.frame.size.width,
                                self.labelDescription.frame.size.height +
                                self.labelDescription.frame.origin.y);
    self.view.frame = newSize;
    }
```

The resizing of the scroll view after adding and resizing my detail view:

```
[self addChildViewController:controllerCustomData];
[self.scrollView addSubview:controllerCustomData.view];    
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0,
                            self.viewElementDetailContentContainer.frame.origin.y,
                            controllerCustomData.view.frame.size.width,
                            controllerCustomData.view.frame.size.height);
controllerCustomData.view.frame = newRect;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, newRect.origin.y + newRect.size.height);
```

So my question is, are there easier ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that does everything you need. You'll need to write the method (maybe methodS) once and use it passing the necessary arguments.